# Select * from x where column is quarter

Tags: sql-server

The following column is part of my table:

[image]

I'd like to start manipulating the table based on the date.  The only date this column will be is 03-31 or 06-30

Something like:

```
Select * from Table1.dbo.TableOne
where Period in 03-31
```

or replace the 03-31 with 06-30

I'm not worried about screening by the year yet.

I guess the question is, how do I screen/filter for the characters from 6 to 11 of the period column.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I converted the column to date and to not include the time

Comment: A "period" has a start, an end, and a duration (1 of the 3 is derived from the other 2, usually duration). If you wish to give a period some name or code to filter by then you don't want a date column for that.

Comment: Why do yo need the same date on so many rows? & by the way, dates are NOT stored they way you seem them on screen (they are stored as sets of numbers)

Comment: There are a bunch of other columns.  Period refers to the last date of the quarter.  If a table has multiple periods in it (i.e. dates ending in 3/31 or 6/30 or 9/30) I want to be able to isolate said "universe."

Comment: @Used_By_Already Thanks for the tip on the way dates are stored.  I did not know that.!  So if I see 2017-03-31... what would be the technical way to screen for it.  I wouldn't say "where period in 2017-03-31" rather...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way is to use [MONTH()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql) and [DAY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/day-transact-sql)

```
Select * 
from Table1.dbo.TableOne
where month(Period) = 3 and day(Period) = 31
;
```

Or [DATEPART()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql) e.g.

```
Select * 
from Table1.dbo.TableOne
where datepart(month,Period) = 3 and datepart(day,Period) = 31
;
```

Because one has to use functions to compare the data to a constant, none of these are super efficient ways to filter big tables.

**Less efficient** ways also exist by **converting dates to strings** and the comparing those e.g.

```
Select * 
from Table1.dbo.TableOne
where right(convert(varchar(8),Period,112),4) = '0331'
;
```

for SQL Server 2012 onward [FORMAT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) is available:

```
Select * 
from Table1.dbo.TableOne
where format(Period,'MMdd') = '0331'
;
```

However I certainly do not encourage anyone to convert dates into strings for filtering, it is mentioned only because you are likely to see such approaches elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @Used_By_Already, both of your first two suggestions worked.  I use them for now but also be thinking about a more efficient way to set up my table or query the date field.